# How to React native application directly without opening Xcode?

Tags: ios, arrays, react-native, react-redux

I am trying to run directly react native application in my iPhone.The 
command `react-native run-ios --device "XXXX device "`
doesnt work for me
Just get.

> installing and launching your app on ***** iPhone6...
>   ** INSTALLATION SUCCEEDED **

```
Unable to mount developer disk image, (Error Domain = com.apple.dtdevicekit Code = 601 "Could not locate device supportfiles."
 UserInfo = {
  DeviceType = iPhone7,
  2,
  NSLocalizedDescription = Could not locate device support files.,
  NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion = This iPhone 6 is running iOS 11.3(15E216),
  which may not be supported by this version of Xcode.
 }) {
 DeviceType = "iPhone7,2";
 NSLocalizedDescription = "Could not locate device support files.";
 NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion = "This iPhone 6 is running iOS 11.3 (15E216), which may not be supported by this version of Xcode."
}
```

> xcodebuild: error: Unable to find a destination matching the provided destination specifier: {
>        id: 2 dcfa6f3928359203a08971f89513000a776d10f
>       }
>
> Unsupported device specifier option.
>   The device“ My Mac” does not support the following options: id
>   Please supply only supported device specifier options.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify `simulator` parameter, read more [Running On Simulator](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-simulator-ios)

```
react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone X"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just run `react-native run-ios` without the specific device name.

if you want to run with the particular device then run first `xcrun simctl list devices` it will list down all the devices and pick up anyone and run with the following command

`react-native run-ios --simulator="DEVICE_NAME"`

ex: `react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 4s"`

Run application on a physical device **

```
ONLY FOR ANDROID
```

**:
follow this steps

#To start adb server

1. adb start-server

#To bind adb with port 8081
2) adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081

#To see the list of devices attached to the system
#Note your mobile/physical device should have developer mode and USB mode should be `Camera P2P`.
3) adb devices

4. react-native run-android

#If APK not install then run next command
5) adb install android/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk

6. react-native start

ref: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-simulator-ios.html#specifying-a-device

Comment: react-native run-ios will only simulator but i want to directly run on usb connected device ..